# Street View Publish API Get list empty {}

Tags: google-streetview-publish

If you upload Google Maps normally, you can see the contributions, and that's it
GET https://streetviewpublish.googleapis.com/v1/photos
Interface return status code 200 json is empty {}
And it was normal before, have you made any restrictions recently

If you upload Google Maps normally, you can see the contributions, and that's it
GET https://streetviewpublish.googleapis.com/v1/photos
Interface return status code 200 json is empty {}
And it was normal before, have you made any restrictions recently